# Different binary file size after converting to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

When I converted a VS 2005 project to VS 2010, with all projects still pointing to compile for the .NET 2.0 Framework, the dlls generated are a totally different file size. Is this normal or something to be concerned about?

Comment: Different as in smaller or larger? Are you compiling as a debug or release build (compiler optimizations on or off)?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in file size is probably due to changes in the compiler shipped with the new version of Visual Studio. In theory, it should be more efficient. It should not be anything to worry about, but that doesn't mean you should forgo testing.

Microsoft does publish information on "Breaking Changes" with the new version of Visual Studio, e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc714070.aspx for VB, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx for C++, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831.aspx for C#.